# What is postMDS doing?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to get a better understanding of what the postMDS function in R's vegan package is actually doing. I tried reading the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/1.2-1/topics/postMDS), but am having a hard time understanding it. I also tried looking at the [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/src/R/postMDS.R), but it doesn't seem to be loading.

Can anyone reframe what the documentation is trying to say in slightly clearer terms? My current level of understanding is that the raw dissimilarity scores are fit to the ordination space for points which are similar "enough" (determined by the threshold parameter). I am guessing a different linear model is fit for each cluster of points, but I am not sure. I also think that the dissimilarity scores are taken as the response variables in the regression. After that, I am sort of lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Update: I did find source code [here](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/blob/master/R/postMDS.R) and am trying to parse through it. I will update this post if I figure it out!

Comment: `postMDS` does centring, rotation and scaling of solution. Your question seems to concern scaling. Running `postMDS(..., plot = TRUE)` will display a plot of rescaling regression. It may help to understand what happens in scaling.